# MarionetteJS: who is responsible for showing sub-applications?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am building a quite simple Marionette application; I am not using Marionette.Module since it's deprecated and since I want to use ES2015 with Webpack.

I have just a couple of "pages": one is the Welcome screen and the other one is the Playground. Each one of those pages are `Applications`, plus there is a root application with a `Layout` with just three regions: header, main and footer.

The view (or layout) of those applications are meant to fill the `main` region of the root layout.

Now, whenever I want to show one of those sub-applications, I don't know exactly how (or, I am not finding the most satisfying way) to ask the Layout of the root application to `showChildView` of the view/layout of those sub-apps.

So far, I came up with two approaches (none of which is fantastic):

**EDIT: I added another approach at the end of the Q**

1. on the controller of each sub-application, trigger the event "application:show" passing in the view. The root application is listening to this event and `showChildView` as soon as it receives the message
2. whenever I start a sub-application, I pass it the root application instance. Whenever the sub-application needs to show itself, it will call the `showChildView` inside the `main` region

The first approach is weak, because it's totally asynchronous (fire and forget). I'd like to know when my application is shown (attached to the DOM) but relying again on another event seems cumbersome

The second approach is more robust but it sucks, because of course I don't want the sub-application's views to be responsible of their own rendering in the root layout. The root application knows better.

Some code follows to try to show both ideas:

```
// Approach #1

// In the root app
welcomeApp.on('app:show', (view) => {
   rootApp.rootView.showChildView('main', view);
});

// In the Welcome sub-app
var Controller = {
    show() {
        app.trigger('app:show', new WelcomeView());
    }
};

// Approach #2

// In the root application
const welcomeApp = new WelcomeApp({
   rootApp: this
});

// In the Welcome sub-app
var Controller = {
    show() {
        app.rootApp.rootLayout.showChildView('main', new WelcomeView());
    }
};
```

**EDIT: 12 Jan.**

OK, digging a bit more in the documentation I found what I think is the correct way to do that. The idea is that the root Application will listen for Commands from the subapplications.

So, in my root view I will have:

```
this.channel.commands.setHandler("application:show", function(view) {
     this.rootView.showChildView('main', view);
}.bind(this));
```

In all the other subapplications, I will have (for example, in the WelcomeView):

```
getController() {

    const greet = function () {
        this.channel.commands.execute('application:show', new WelcomeView());
    }.bind(this);

    return {
        greet: greet
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't use multiple applications, this seems to be just getting around the issue of modules being removed. Have you tried using a single application with a LayoutView, a Region for each component or (module) and the base of the component either being a singleton JS object, or you could try [Backbone.Service](https://github.com/thejameskyle/backbone.service) to split it up. If you are using multiple routes, you could have a look at [Backbone.Routing](https://github.com/thejameskyle/backbone-routing), with each Route being the base 'controller' for the 'page'.

I find a brilliant architecture for large scale Marionette applications is James Kyle's [Marionette Wires](https://github.com/thejameskyle/marionette-wires). This uses Service for reusable components, and routers/routes for different data types.

**EDIT**

Another way of architecting using services, but if you don't want the root application's regions show methods to be called from child components, would be to import the instantiated application into the child component and use the app.addRegions method to add regions within the child. EG

```
//app.js
import { Application } from 'backbone.marionette';

const App = Application.extend({
  onStart() {
    //doSomething();
  }...
});

export const app = new App();

//submodule/service.js
import { Service } from 'backbone.service';
import { SubmoduleController } from './controller';

const SubmoduleService = Service.extend({
  requests() {
    show: 'show',
    hide: 'hide'
  },

  setup(options = {}) {
    this.el = options.el
  },

  start() {
    this.controller = new SubmoduleController({
      el: this.el
    });
  },

  show() {
    this.controller.show();
  },

  hide() {
    this.controller.destroy();
  }
});

export const submoduleService = new SubmoduleService();

//submodule/controller.js
import { Object as Controller, Region } from 'backbone.marionette';
import { View } from './view';
import { app } from '../app';

export const SubmoduleController = Controller.extend({
  initialize(options = {}) {
    this.el = options.el;
    this._addRegions();
  },

  _addRegions() {
    const region = new Region({
      el: this.el
    });

    app.addRegions({
      submoduleRegion: region
    });
  },

  show() {
    const view = new View();
    app.submoduleRegion.show(view);
  },

  onDestroy() {
    app.submoduleRegion.reset();
  }
});

//main.js
import { submoduleService } from './submodule/service';

const config = {
  submodule: {
    el: '#submodule';
  },
  ...
};

submoduleService.setup(config.submodule);
submoduleService.show();
```

A gotcha with doing it this way is the submodule's region needs it's element to exist in the DOM when it's region's show method is called. This can either be achieved by having a root view on the application, whose template contains all component root elems, or to have a root submodule - page or something.

Comment: That's really an interesting thought. I didn't know about Wires (thanks for the link), and I also didn't think about using Services. I am still not sure if they would fit my application the way I've layied it out, though. I am quite experienced with Backbone but I haven't had tried Marionette, so I didn't even considered Modules in the first place, since they are deprecated.


I do not dislike the idea of "encapsulated" Applications which talks together via the Radio. Let's see if how can I use those services!

Comment: The thing I don't like about Wires, now that I've dug a bit into it, is that the services call the `this.container.show` method, which is exactly the point of my question. I don't like the "children" to call a method of the parent... I know that it's basically the same than sending messages, but since everything is event based, this single thing bothers me :)